# Change date difference with CASE calculation

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

I have a holding table for data, before adding to a final table in my database.

Within that table is a datediff calculation, which returns the number of days in a month.

However, this is baased on projects and what I need to do is look up the Project ID in another table, to see whether the TimeID (Year/Month) is equal to either the Start- or End-Date of the project.

When it matches either, it needs to change the number of days for that month to either Month-Start to Project-Finish (if it's the end month) or Project-Start to Month-End (if it's the start month).

I've tried to do this with the following script but I get the errors:

```
*** This bit is sorted, please see below ***
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.
*** This bit is sorted, please see below ***
```

*** EDIT ***
Thanks to Anton, I've added the required END to my CASE statement, but I now get a different set of errors (probably down to my syntax):

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'TimeID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Invalid column name 'TimeID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Invalid column name 'ID'.
```

Please help if you can.

The script is:

```
UPDATE FAC
SET FAC.[SignedData] = 
CASE
    WHEN FAC.[TIMEID] = A.[Start_TimeID] THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN pd.[Start_Date] >= GETDATE() THEN datediff(day,pd.[Start_Date],pt.[Period_End])
            WHEN pd.[Start_Date] < GETDATE() THEN datediff(day,GETDATE(),pt.[Period_End])
        END

    WHEN FAC.[TIMEID] = A.[End_TimeID] THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN pd.[End_Date] >= GETDATE() THEN datediff(day,getdate(),pd.[End_Date])
            WHEN pd.[End_Date] < GETDATE() THEN '0'
        END
    END
FROM Temp_Fac2Programme FAC
JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        pd.[TimeID], pd.[Start_TimeID], pd.[End_TimeID], pt.[Period_Start], pt.[Period_End]
    FROM ProjectDates pd
    JOIN ProjectTimeID pt
        on pd.[TimeID] = pt.[TimeID]
    ) A

ON A.[ID] = FAC.[Project]

Where   A.[ID] = FAC.[Project]

GO
```

NB - SIGNEDDATA is the number of days in the month.

*** Example Data ***

Temp_Fac2Programme (FAC) contains:

```
ACCOUNT             CATEGORY        DATASRC     PROFITCENTRE    PROJECT         RPTCURRENCY     TIMEID          SIGNEDDATA      SOURCE
REMAIN_DAYS_FLAG    ACTUAL          DS_FLAGS    B9059           AAA_7915_BBOY   LC              20130100        34.0000000000   0
```

ProjectDates (pd) contains:

```
PROJECT_ID      START_TIMEID    END_TIMEID  START_DATE  END_DATE    TOTAL_DAYS
PAG_5244_CASH   20110400        20120300    2011-04-01  2012-03-31  365
```

ProjectTimeID (pt) contains:

```
TIMEID      PERIOD_START    PERIOD_END  DAYS_IN_PERIOD  PCMONTHSTAT
20140600    2014-05-31      2014-06-27  27              F
```

Comment: For your first `CASE`, there is no corresponding `END` (unless I missed something)

Comment: D'oh.  Thanks Anton.  It allows it to run, but gives different error instead.  Please see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current (edited) version, it's basically what error messages say:

You use `pd.[TimeID]` in two places, but there is no `TimeID` column in `ProjectDates` (for now, I have no idea what you meant here).

Your subquery (aliased to `A`) has no `ID` column. The likely fix is adding `pd.[Project_ID] as ID` into the subquery's list of selected fields.

Comment: Thanks Anton.  Turns out I was being stupid/tired/lazy and not working the errors properly before giving up.  I ended up having to JOIN a third table to the query and rename a couple of lookups, which seems to have nailed it.  Cheers.